# How to select all checkboxes but unselect a particular checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I'm create a list of checkbox and create a another checkbox, when I click that check box all listed checkbox are selected but when I unselect a checkbox all checkboxes are unselected. Here is my code :

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (change)="inviteAll()" [(ngModel)]="checked">
    <ul>
    <li class="peopleselectlist-item" *ngFor="let connection of connections">
        <img *ngIf="connection.imageUrl === '' || connection.imageUrl === null" src="assets/images/default_user.png" alt="" class="connection-img">
        <img *ngIf="connection.imageUrl !== '' && connection.imageUrl !== null" src="{{connection.imageUrl}}" alt="" class="connection-img">
         <h5>{{connection.firstName}}</h5>
         <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="{{connection.userId}}" (change)="tagUser(connection.userId)" [(ngModel)]="checked">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span></label> </li> <ul>
```

How to solve this problem. When I'm delesect a checkox only that check box are unselect.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="checked"` both ngModel are same no, that's why all get unchecked, also post your `tagUser()` method

Comment: `tagUser` is likely unrelated.  You were already correct with `[(ngModel)]="checked"`... @Santu , You are mapping all of the checkboxes to the same variable, so when you update it to "false" on one, all of the checkboxes get unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Try to add index value for uniqueness. Like This:

`*ngFor="let connection of connections;let i = index"`

and change `[(ngModel)]="checked"` to  `[(ngModel)]="checked[i]"` and create array of checked in ts/js file. Also try to `id={{i}}` in checkbox field.